# Sending multi-level categories in Product data for Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm implementing Google tag manager for product view on web e-Commerce.

In a [document from Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data), it says about category attribute.

> The category to which the product belongs (e.g. Apparel). Use / as a delimiter to specify up to 5-levels of hierarchy (e.g. Apparel/Men/T-Shirts).

So we can send multi-level categories separated by forward slash. But what if category name, for example, is "3/4 inches". How can we escape it to make sure that it will be one-level category name in GA Dashboard.

In additional, if I would like to send 2-level categories:

- Level1: Screws
- Level2: 3/4 inches

How could we send data in category attribute ?

As I worked around so far, I've tried

- In JS, `categoryname.replace(/\//g,'\/')`
- In JS, `categoryname.replace(/\//g,'-')`
- In JS, `categoryname.replace(/\//g,'%26')`

But I don't know what is the best practice for this.

Thank you in advance.

Link to [Stack Exchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104251/sending-multi-level-categories-in-product-data-for-google-analytics)

Comment: you could also try getting help here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @DaImTo
I did not found similar question.
So it has been added there.